# Проблема с расположением футера и текста в нём

Tags: html, css

Футер постоянно прилегает к верху
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

и на других страниц тоже самое, а должно прилегать прямо к низу.
И ещё одна проблема то что текст Соц. кнопки и иконка вк находится где-то по центру, а должно находится на футере в правом нижнем углу, помогите решить проблемы пожалуйста, вот мой проект https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Z4yviyLo6kYyYcNFeQK7X6viJw6AhdCN

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть несколько способов прижать футер к низу экрана, можешь посмотреть примеры в этой статье (способы описанные здесь всегда мне помогали в этом вопросе)
http://dimox.name/press_footer_bottom_with_css/ или в этой http://w3.org.ua/html/prizhimaem-futer-k-nizu-stranitsyi/

По поводу Соц. кнопки. Чотбы прижать ее к правому углу можно использовать float:right, но смотри чтобы ширина блока в котором находится соц.кнопка была равна ширине футера, а ширина футера была 100% (но судя по скрину ширина футера и так 100 % так как белая полоса на весь экран)

Comment: сп, с футером разобрался, но вот с текстом не понял как

Comment: Я посмотрел, с текстом странная штука. Из-за того, что размер картинки указат в процентах она не становится четко справа. Если задашь в пикселях, то будет норм.

Comment: сп, я попробую сделать так